# InvalidAttributeIdentifierException: [LDAP: error code 17 - Object Class: AttributeDescription contains inappropriate characters]

Tags: java, openldap

I am getting the follwing error

> javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeIdentifierException: [LDAP: error code 17 - Object Class: AttributeDescription contains inappropriate characters];

This is my Class:

```
public class OpenLDAPTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "ldap://localhost:389";
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
    try {
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        System.out.println("connected");
        System.out.println(ctx.getEnvironment());
        System.out.println("Creating subContext");
        String name = "dc=mine, dc=com";
        Attributes atrs = new BasicAttributes();
        Attribute atr1 = new BasicAttribute("Object Class");
        atr1.add("OrgPerson");
        atrs.put(atr1);
        Attribute atr2 = new BasicAttribute("cn");
        atr2.add("sathish");
        atrs.put(atr2);
        atrs.put("Phone", "12345");
        Context c = ctx.createSubcontext(name, atrs);
        System.out.println(c.getEnvironment());
        ctx.close();

    } catch (AuthenticationNotSupportedException ex) {
        System.out.println("The authentication is not supported by the server");
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        System.out.println("incorrect password or username");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        //System.out.println("error when trying to create the context");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have an attribute named "Object Class"? (the space is probably the issue). According to https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/dss_admin/prep_ldap.html it probably should be "objectclass"

Comment: Actually I am not that much good in LDAP, I saw some code in net, its worked with ApacheDirectoryStudio, then Iam trying for OpenLDAP, my intention is to write code for accessing openLDAP using java

Comment: I have changed to "objectclass" but still getting the same error... Do you know, how to use those LDAP queries in java? If you Know please guide me.. Thank you